# HeapSetInformation return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c++, memory-management

I run my application with visual studio 2008 service pack1(9.0.30729.1), windows 7  professional 64bit with 8 GB memory

My application is 32bit process and use /LARGEADDRESSAWARE option

To reduce memory fragmentation, i adjust sample code
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366705(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define HEAP_LFH 2

int __cdecl _tmain()
{
    BOOL bResult;
    HANDLE hHeap;
    ULONG HeapInformation;

    //
    // Enable heap terminate-on-corruption. 
    // A correct application can continue to run even if this call fails, 
    // so it is safe to ignore the return value and call the function as follows:
    // (void)HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);
    // If the application requires heap terminate-on-corruption to be enabled, 
    // check the return value and exit on failure as shown in this example.
    //
    bResult = HeapSetInformation(NULL,
                                 HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption,
                                 NULL,
                                 0);

    if (bResult != FALSE) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Heap terminate-on-corruption has been enabled.\n"));
    }
    else {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to enable heap terminate-on-corruption with LastError %d.\n"),
                 GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    //
    // Create a new heap with default parameters.
    //
    hHeap = HeapCreate(0, 0, 0);
    if (hHeap == NULL) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to create a new heap with LastError %d.\n"),
                 GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    //
    // Enable the low-fragmenation heap (LFH). Starting with Windows Vista, 
    // the LFH is enabled by default but this call does not cause an error.
    //
    HeapInformation = HEAP_LFH;
    bResult = HeapSetInformation(hHeap,
                                 HeapCompatibilityInformation,
                                 &HeapInformation,
                                 sizeof(HeapInformation));
    if (bResult != FALSE) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("The low-fragmentation heap has been enabled.\n"));
    }
    else {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Failed to enable the low-fragmentation heap with LastError %d.\n"),
                 GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

bResult = HeapSetInformation(hHeap,
      HeapCompatibilityInformation,
      &HeapInformation,
      sizeof(HeapInformation));

bResult is false and getLastError is 87(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)

how to fix this?

Comment: Don't know why that got a negative vote. It's describing exactly the problem I just had and provides enough information and research into the error to be precisely answered. +1

Answer (score 2):

> [The LFH also cannot be enabled if you are using the heap debugging
>   tools in Debugging Tools for Windows or Microsoft Application
>   Verifier.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Running the linked sample code under the VS2010 debugger produces the exact same failure for me. Running without debugging (Ctrl-F5), it succeeds as expected.

However, from the same article:

> The information in this topic applies to Windows Server 2003 and
>   Windows XP. Starting with Windows Vista, the system uses the
>   low-fragmentation heap (LFH) as needed to service memory allocation
>   requests. *Applications do not need to enable the LFH for their
>   heaps*.

So basically, **the best fix is to not do it at all**.

If you *really, really, really, **must*** specifically support XP/2k3 even with their end looming;

> To enable the low-fragmentation heap when running under a debugger, set the _NO_DEBUG_HEAP environment variable to 1.